# Regex - Capture all text up until Capital Letter across new lines?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string in python:

```
sample_string = """STEVE SMITH, AMERICAN DAD : Good morning, good 
afternoon, usa . Before I hand over to  Homer, I want to give a quick reminder of the cartoons we are making.  
 
Numbers in the presentation today. Our focus is now on reported num bers, but we will call out and 
specify notable items . we like films and ultimately benefit your schedule going 
forward . Homer, over to you.  
 
HOMER SIMPSON, HEAD OF SIMPSON HOUSEHOLD:  Thanks, Steve, and good morning in China, 
good afternoon in welcome to our viewership results call . Beans is 
going to lead the presentation, but I’d like to make some opening comments.  
 
We’ve announced about 1000 hours viewing time, so our strategy is working."""
```

The string is over multiple lines and sentences, i am trying to write a regex to capture two groups - one group is the person speaking, the other is the text associated with them.

So trying to get an output like:

```
output_string_1 = ("""STEVE SMITH, AMERICAN DAD""", """Good morning, good 
afternoon, usa . Before I hand over to  Homer, I want to give a quick reminder of the cartoons we are making.  
 
Numbers in the presentation today. Our focus is now on reported num bers, but we will call out and 
specify notable items . we like films and ultimately benefit your schedule going 
forward . Homer, over to you.  """ )

output_string_2 = ("""HOMER SIMPSON, HEAD OF SIMPSON HOUSEHOLD""", """Thanks, Steve, and good morning in China, 
good afternoon in welcome to our viewership results call . Beans is 
going to lead the presentation, but I’d like to make some opening comments.  
 
We’ve announced about 1000 hours viewing time, so our strategy is working.""" )
```

The output can be a list of Tuples instead of what i have done above.

I have the following regex so far:

`^([^a-z:]+?)\s*:\s*(.|\n?)`

The text should stop capturing the next group when it encounters a new speaker who is always identified by CAPITAL LETTERS and a COLON :

so a positive lookahead i think is needed - any ideas?

Python 3.9.X is being used and re package

Comment: If you want to solve it with a pure regex, yes. Instead you could also find all occurrences of the speaker pattern and associate the part in between as spoken words to the previous speaker in a simple for-loop.

Comment: I'd use `r'(?sm)^[A-Z][A-Z\W]*:.*?(?=\n[A-Z][A-Z\W]*:|\z)'`. It is risky to rely on the fact there are always two or more uppercase letters in each word before the colon. Besides, there can always be more than just `,` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex find all approach using `re.findall`:

```py
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2,}(?:,? [A-Z]{2,})+\s*:.*?(?=\s*[A-Z]{2,}(?:,? [A-Z]{2,})+\s*:|$)', sample_string, flags=re.S)
print(matches)

#['STEVE SMITH, AMERICAN DAD : Good morning, good \nafternoon, usa . Before I hand over to  Homer, I want to give a quick reminder of the cartoons we are making.  \n \nNumbers in the presentation today. Our focus is now on reported num bers, but we will call out and \nspecify notable items . we like films and ultimately benefit your schedule going \nforward . Homer, over to you.',
# 'HOMER SIMPSON, HEAD OF SIMPSON HOUSEHOLD:  Thanks, Steve, and good morning in China, \ngood afternoon in welcome to our viewership results call . Beans is \ngoing to lead the presentation, but I\xe2\x80\x99d like to make some opening comments.  \n \nWe\xe2\x80\x99ve announced about 1000 hours viewing time, so our strategy is working.']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `[A-Z]{2,}` a leading uppercase word
- `(?:,? [A-Z]{2,})+` optional following uppercase words
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `:` colon
- `.*?` match all content, across lines, until reaching
- `(?=\s*[A-Z]{2,}(?:,? [A-Z]{2,})+\s*:|$)` either whitespace and
  the next uppercase word OR
  the end of the samples string

Comment: If there are capital words such as MOVIES inside a string when a speaker speaks, the regex pattern above won't work - is there way to overcome this, i.e. it still captures up until next speaker even if there are CAPITAL words?

Comment: Yes, check the edit.  Just look for a series of uppercase letters which is followed by colon.

Answer (score 0):

With specific regex matching:

```
groups = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{2,}[A-Z, ]+[A-Z]+) ?: ?(.+?)(?=[A-Z]{2,}|$)',
                    sample_string, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(groups)
```

---

```
[('STEVE SMITH, AMERICAN DAD', 'Good morning, good \nafternoon, usa . Before I hand over to  Homer, I want to give a quick reminder of the cartoons we are making.  \n\nNumbers in the presentation today. Our focus is now on reported num bers, but we will call out and \nspecify notable items . we like films and ultimately benefit your schedule going \nforward . Homer, over to you.  \n\n'), ('HOMER SIMPSON, HEAD OF SIMPSON HOUSEHOLD', ' Thanks, Steve, and good morning in China, \ngood afternoon in welcome to our viewership results call . Beans is \ngoing to lead the presentation, but I’d like to make some opening comments.  \n\nWe’ve announced about 1000 hours viewing time, so our strategy is working.')]
```